# Vue Router push Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router

Is there a way to avoid Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location. I need to do a pagination, this is the method:

```
handlePageChange(page: number): void {
  const query = {
    ...this.$route.query,
    page: page.toString(),
  };
  this.$router.push({ name: 'PageName', query });
}
```

and I keep getting error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/page-path?page=2".
```

I tried doing a catch with the router but that does not work. Can someone help me shed some light what am i doing wrong here? :/

Comment: Actually, you are trying to navigate to the same page where you are currently, that's why you are having the navigation duplicated error.
Ex: You are on xyz page and you are again trying to navigate to the same xyz page.

Comment: You can also try this `this.$router.push({ name: 'PageName', query }).catch(err => {})`

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution it seems to work on the first page to second, if i navigate to the third and so on it won't work and cmiw also that it just suppresses the error message.

Comment: You can try adding a condition that if current path/query is not same as the path to route then only change the path otherwise not.
`if (this.$route.path !== path) this.$router.push(path)`

Answer (score 6):

If it's safe to ignore, and you are using vue-router `^3.4.0`, you can do:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const { isNavigationFailure, NavigationFailureType } = VueRouter
...
this.$router.push(fullPath).catch(error => {
  if (!isNavigationFailure(error, NavigationFailureType.duplicated)) {
    throw Error(error)
  }
})
```

Or handle it globally:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const { push } = VueRouter.prototype

const { isNavigationFailure, NavigationFailureType } = VueRouter

VueRouter.prototype.push = function (location) {
  return push.call(this, location).catch(error => {
    if (!isNavigationFailure(error, NavigationFailureType.duplicated)) {
      throw Error(error)
    }
  })
}

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

For more details, please refer to [Navigation Failures](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html).

Comment: how do you do the global thingy in nuxt 2

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit dated, but merging both existing answers for a cleaner, global handling:

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const { isNavigationFailure, NavigationFailureType } = VueRouter;

const originalPush = VueRouter.prototype.push;
VueRouter.prototype.push = function push(location) {
    original_push.call(this, location).catch(error => {
        if(!isNavigationFailure(error, NavigationFailureType.duplicated)) {
            throw Error(error)
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: how would write this global handler in nuxt 2

Answer (score 2):

You can globally handle this problem.
Open your router's index file (index.js) and use this code inside it-

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

// Handle navigation duplication for router push (Globally)

const originalPush = VueRouter.prototype.push;
VueRouter.prototype.push = function push(location) {
  return originalPush.call(this, location).catch((error) => {
  });
};
```

Try this example - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-glitter-re97k?file=/src/App.vue)

Cheers!

Comment: You should never silently catch broad errors.